# I am trying to solve on of Hacke rank problem - Sherlock and the Valid String but my coding is failing for 2 test cases

Tags: java, string

Sherlock considers a string to be valid if all characters of the string appear the same number of times. It is also valid if he can remove just **1** character at **1** index in the string, and the remaining characters will occur the same number of times. Given a string , determine if it is valid. If so, return YES, otherwise return NO.

For example, if s=abc, it is a valid string because frequencies are **{a:1,b:1,c:1}**. So is **s=abcc** because we can remove one **c** and have **1** of each character in the remaining string. If **s=abcc** however, the string is not valid as we can only remove **1** occurrence of **c**. That would leave character frequencies of **{a:1,b:1,c:1}**.

Function Description

Complete the isValid function in the editor below. It should return either the string **YES** or the string **NO**.

isValid has the following parameter(s):

s: a string

**Input Format**

A single string .

Constraints

1 <= |s| <=10^5
Each character s[i] asciii[a-z]

**Output Format**

Print YES if string  is valid, otherwise, print NO.

**Sample Input 0**
aabbcd
**Sample Output 0**
NO

**Sample Input 1**
aabbccddeefghi

**Sample Output 1**
NO

Below is my code -

```
static String isValid(String s1) {
    int arr[]  = new int[26];
    final String YES = "YES";
    final String NO = "NO";
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
        arr[s1.charAt(i)-'a']++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int i=0;
    while(arr[i] == 0){
        i++;
    }
    int min=i;
    int max=25;
    String isValid = NO;
    if(arr[min] == arr[max]) return isValid=YES;
    else if(arr[max]-arr[min] == 1){
        if( arr[max-1] == arr[min]) return isValid=YES;
        if( arr[min]==1 && arr[min+1] == arr[max]) return isValid=YES;
    }

    return isValid;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line causes the problem:

```java
if(arr[max]-arr[min] ==1 && arr[min]==1 && arr[min+1] == arr[max]) return isValid=YES;
```

What do you want to do with `arr[min+1] == arr[max]`? It looks like you want to check if you could just add the character with the fewest appearances. The task does not require this. Just remove that if clause. Then it should work.

Comment: What did you add?

Comment: Thanks for the reply 0x4b50. I have added the condition for the below scenario. If my input is String s1 = "abbcc". Since my array is sorted it will have the values arr[]{1,2,2} at indexes(23,24,25).So to make the string valid I have to remove 'a' so that it will have 2 characters of b and c. So I am using the check if my arr[23+1] is equals to arr[25]. So I think the condition should present.

Comment: Yes, but this result should return NO because you could only remove a `b` OR a `c` but not both to match the occurences of `a`. It is also forbidden to add an `a` because the task only mentions the removal of characters. Did my solution work?

Comment: Could you please stop to delete and modify your comments over and over again? Just add a comment.

Comment: You're right. Please provide an example were your code is not working.

Comment: Please click the below link for the input string.https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/8816/input07.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1588787047&Signature=scAcbm3uvcLpArViZeqSD0g2VSk%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Answer (score 0):

This had taken a lot time, Finally I found what the issue is. I have updated my below else if condition.

```
  `else if(arr[max]-arr[min] == 1){
        if( arr[max-1] == arr[min]) return isValid=YES;
        if( arr[min]==1 && arr[min+1] == arr[max]) return isValid=YES;
    }`                                                                                 
  with
```

`else{
        if(arr[max]-arr[min] == 1 && arr[max-1] == arr[min]) return isValid=YES;
        if(arr[min]==1 && arr[min+1] == arr[max]) return isValid=YES;
    }`
 Problem is when the input String is **s1 = "abbbbbb"** since we can remove 1 character **a** it should return **Yes** but my code is returning **NO** because of the condition `if(arr[max]-arr[min] == 1)`